# not able to send multi string/ a sentence as a body in terminal notifier

Tags: shell, terminal, scripting, notifications, desktop-application

i want to send a "multi string/a sentence" as a message in desktop notification using terminal-notifier

throught terminal its easy, it works as below

**Command:**

`terminal-notifier -title 'testing' -message 'multi string with spaces'`

**output**

[image]

but when i do the same thing through shell script, it will not work :(

**shell script:**

`msg="multi string with space"
echo $msg
terminal-notifier -title 'testing' -message $msg`

**output**

[image]

So basically its not taking the words/characters after space ...

Any thoughts/Answers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to quote variables !

```
msg="multi string with space"
echo "$msg"
terminal-notifier -title 'testing' -message "$msg"
```

"Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: Queno, thanks for the links and detailed explanation :)

Comment: I prefer Gilles, but up2u ;) You're welcome (or at least Queno**t**)

Comment: sorry @Gilles , in the excitement of getting the solution to my question , i missed that :)